# Using Nuget on VS2015 RC Tools for Apache Cordova

Tags: visual-studio, cordova, nuget, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-cordova

Bit of a newbie to VS2015RC with Cordova but I have a query regarding how to use Nuget to add dependencies like say Jquery, Angular etc.

If you add the dependencies or packages using Nuget then they are added to the root of the Project (Not in the www folder). Of course you can just move the files but this plays havoc with some of the Source Control we are using and also you have to remember to move it back again to the root if you want to "Upgrade" the dependency or package with Nuget again.

So....

1. Is there a way of getting Nuget to install the files in the correct
   sub-folder? or...
2. Is there another way to add the dependencies /
   packages (Npm etc?) and is there a tutorial around for that?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I understood it, the directory structure was changed in the RC. I chalked the wrong directory up to the nuget configs not being updated yet. I expect the gold release to have that fixed.

Comment: Ok. So it wasn't me being a bit dumb and missing something. Many thanks for the answer.

Comment: Well I wouldn't say it's about being dumb - I find the documentation very lacking, the whole toolset very 'fresh' and in general, the development experience to be underwhelming, to say the least. The fact that I had to refer to a book on PhoneGap/Cordova (which itself is filled with 'yeah this whole thing is a moving target, oh and you have to fix this and this problem yourself by copying files manually no matter what the Cordova docs say') to understand what's going on, doesn't scream 'this is production quality software' to me.

Comment: Nice... new structure, old CTP projects are broken and NuGet currently doesn't work with the new Cordova structure (can't even install angular core package). That's annoying...