# VS 2015 Cordova structure and NuGet

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-cordova

I am working on a Win81 Cordova app. It seems that the default install location for NuGet packages is not quite right. I am sure I am doing this wrong, but I do not know which part I should do differently.

From a fresh Cordova app in 2015, I add WinJS via NuGet. This puts WinJS in a folder at the project level. However, the new structure in 2015 seems to want this in the www folder. I can move the WinJS folder down, but I am curious if that is a sign I am structuring this incorrectly. What would be the standard approach in this case?

- Move the WinJS to the www
- Tell NuGet to put WinJS in www (I don't see how to do this)
- Leave WinJS in project root and reference it there (I haven't been able to make this work yet)
- User a different PM for Cordova apps

Comment: This may be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30097425/using-nuget-on-vs2015-rc-tools-for-apache-cordova. However, as of VS 2015 RTM, this still seems to be a mismatch? I appologize if this is truly a dupe. In that case, how can I "refresh" the original to get current feedback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NuGet puts the WinJS files in the project root to support Windows Store app development, so yes, for Cordova apps it needs to be moved to the www folder.

Comment: Would a Cordova app not need it in root for store deployment?

Comment: No, it would need to be in www folder. There will be a workaround published for this compatibility issue with Cordova/Nuget soon.

Comment: Glad this is getting fixed, I had to also find out, by trail-and-error that I had to drag the WinJS folder down a level to the www folder. Tried altering the src attribute of the script element but you can't point 'up' the way.